# Black screen with cursor after login

Tags: windows-10, black-screen-of-death

This question has been [asked before](https://superuser.com/questions/948556/windows-10-black-screen-with-working-cursor-after-login), but none of the answers worked for me.

## Details

After about 5 minutes and 41 seconds (yes, I timed it), my desktop shows up as normal.

It only happens on one account; other accounts are unaffected.

**During the black screen:**

- CPU: ~12%.
- Disk: ~6%
- Ethernet: random spikes.

...Which is pretty much equal to my idle usage, once windows starts properly.

Looking at the task manager and sorting by CPU usage, *wsappx* was the biggest task, at ~12%.

Once Windows actually *starts*, everything seems to work normally.

### Functional things

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> - Works as expected.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> - Brings up task manager.
Task manager - Works, that's where I got the numbers above from. Doesn't show any foreground tasks running, spare task manager itself.

### Non-functional things

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - Nope.
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> - Nope.

---

**Device specs**

ThinkStation P320 Signature Edition
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.2GHz
System type: 64-bit OS, x64-based processor
Graphics card: Radeon(TM) RX 460 Graphics
*[Full output of dxdiag](https://pastebin.com/NvS0BSuB)*

**Windows**

Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version: 1709
OS Build: 16299.309

---

If none of the answers below work for you, don't panic! Do research, find one that does, and then *post an answer documenting what you did* to help others!

Comment: Does it have a discrete graphics card?

Comment: Yes; HMB while I find out which one.

Comment: Please [edit] your questions whenever you need to add additional information. That said, and before anything else, install/update the graphics drivers.

Comment: Does it behave the same way if you log in as a different user?  How about if you start Windows in Safe Mode?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Other user accounts are fine; I'll get back to you on the safe mode.

Comment: When it happens and you bring up task manager, do you see any application running? It might be some sort of application running full screen

Comment: @YisroelTech Aside from background tasks? No, just Task Manager.

Comment: Then look at the Details tab (or in the background Tasks) and see if you can observe anything there that disappears after the 5 minutes and 41 seconds

Comment: If it' sonly with your user, then it's something in your user profile.  Check the registry user-level for references to printers, network locations, etc. that no longer exist, as you might be stuck waiting for them to time-out.   Easiest fix:  Copy your data to a folder outside of your profile, delete your profile, create  anew one, and copy data back.  Have you checked the Event Log for errors/failures during boot?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 "Event log" -- I confess to having no idea what that is.

Comment: The Event log is a log of system events; you can view it with the Event Viewer. :)

Comment: I had to log in again, and looked at task manager; a background process called *wsappx* is using most of the cpu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Black Screen with working cursor after login](https://superuser.com/questions/948556/windows-10-black-screen-with-working-cursor-after-login)

Answer (score 0):

First, I updated everything: Windows, graphics card drivers, etc. Reboot to apply.

Then, I started regedit, and made these changes. In
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\AppXSVC` and
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\ClipSVC`

Change the "Start" REG_DWORD value from 0x3 to 0x4.

Reboot to apply.

---

This can be achieved with this .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\AppXSVC]
"Start"=dword:4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\ClipSVC]
"Start"=dword:4
```

Paste into a file, save it as `killwsappx.reg`, double-click.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out to be the `exlporer.exe` process (which renders the icons on your Desktop and deals with your Taskbar etc.) that wasn't starting up properly.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up the Task Manager, click on `File` and then on `Run new task`. Then enter `explorer.exe`.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 home 64 bit v 1709 build 16299.371 - 2 users
core i5-6600 8GB,GeForce GTX 970
I did system restores, tried most of the suggested solutions but the problem kept coming back for one user. Finally removed and reinstalled the user. OK for a week now. Life's too short to be wasting precious time with a piece of plastic.